# Adding "all" category to ggplots2 plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, density-plot

**Question**

Suppose I want to make density plots for each categories with an additional category of "all" points. How would I go about creating such a figure? Is there a way other than duplicating all points with an "all" category?

*Example*

```
library('ggplot2')
fig <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) + 
       stat_density(geom = "line", position = "identity")
```

which will output the following figure:

[image: http://127.0.0.1:16553/chunk_output/8D7C71B83681FBD4/144E3B0/cby49jvbfsi3m/00001b.png]

However, I would like to include another line that contains all of the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) + 
  stat_density(geom = "line", position = "identity") + 
  stat_density(aes(x = Sepal.Length, color = "all"), geom = "line")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How would I update the legend to reflect the addition of "all" category?

Comment: @onepint16oz you could use `aes(color = "all")` inside the second density instead of `color = 1` *outside* of an `aes`, and you'll get a line labeled `"all"` in the legend

Comment: Sorry I did not notice the legend issue and went sleeping. Thanks for your suggestion camille, I have updated my answer, I hope you don't mind.